# Yet Another Model to Identify, Dark Grey Motorcycles?

Tags: set-identification

I have looked and looked through Google images to find this one.  I'm also fairly certain that I don't have the major assembly connected to each other correctly.  But does someone know what the set number is for this one?
[image: 3-wheeled]

Answer (score 7):

Looks like [RoboRiders 8516-1 The Boss:](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8516-1)

[image: set picture]